# Converting py file to exe

Tags: python, exe

I have a .py file from my `Portable Python 2.7.5.1`. I've tried using `cxFreeze`, `py2exe` and `pyinstaller` and can't seem to get it working. The only module I am using in my code is `easygui 0.95`. Any advice?

Comment: Ive heard you need to stand in the center of a pentagram and chant beatles songs backwards in order to make these work ..... Or at least provide some more details ... preferably with one specific tool chain(eg pyinstaller)

Comment: Ive installed py2exe again for python 2.7.6 but when i run the setup.py i get this
C:\Python27>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
creating C:\Python27\build
creating C:\Python27\build\bdist.win32
creating C:\Python27\build\bdist.win32\winexe
creating C:\Python27\build\bdist.win32\winexe\collect-2.7
creating C:\Python27\build\bdist.win32\winexe\bundle-2.7
creating C:\Python27\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp
creating C:\Python27\dist
*** searching for required modules ***
error: D: No such file or directory